# Raspberry Pi Emulation in OSX

Tags: emulation, macos

Is there an emulator for Raspberry Pi that I could use to try to familiarise myself with the environment?

And in my case something that will work on OSX.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of Linux question - please consider answering the question as pertaining to OSX - preferably with something nicely packaged. Really do not want to be hacking around with Linux package managers.

Comment: Although a duplicate, this is still a useful question to have, so I have undeleted it. I hope that's okay. It's also a well asked one, so I have  given you an upvote as well.

Comment: How about a vote to reopen it as well? :)

Comment: The problem is that the answer would be almost identical to that Linux question. I think we'll have to let the community make that decision.

Comment: By the way, if you don't agree with any decisions then you can always raise your opinions on [meta] or in [chat].

Comment: +1 for reopen. OS X isn't discussed in the other answer (it isn't linux), only Arch/Ubuntu are covered.

Comment: @AlexL Would building and using QEMU be any different on OSX?

Comment: @Jivings Would it not be worth including installation instructions for QEMU on OSX?

Comment: @AlexL Well, it depends if they are any different!

Comment: @Jivings I'd be able to tell you if the question was opened and answered!

Comment: @AlexL Well you only need one more vote ;) From what I can see though, the process is identical.

Answer (score 1):

See this post re. using VirtualBox to run a virtualized version of Ubuntu. It comes configured with QEMU to emulate the ARM CPU and run Debian on ARM.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=2961&hilit=virtualbox

It doesn't provide any emulation of the Pi's hardware interfaces though, if that's what you're looking for, it just provides a virtualized copy of the OS.